# Reverse shell - outgoing connections created automatically in spite they being terminated

Tags: shell, reverse-tunnel

My Win 10 computer has been hacked and is creating automatic reverse shell connections to different IP Addresses (spoofed as Google and Microsoft IP's). Each time I terminate these connections they connect back within a couple of seconds.

How do I stop these reverse shell connections from connecting back?
Which location do I look in my computer to block this?

Note: I have Norton internet security & firewalls but this isn't effective.

Comment: @kamil-maciorowski, how is a question a garbage... I guess that must be yourself.

Comment: The garbage is what I have removed, not what is left. Check the [revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/1699646/revisions) and see what I have removed. It's the private feedback Stack Overflow had given you and you apparently pasted it here carelessly. As a part of your question on Super User the message makes no sense, that's why I called it "garbage". Don't you agree it should have been removed from the question?